# Problemas al mostrar un campo en un text solo lo puedo mostrar con un select

Tags: laravel, formularios, pdf, eloquent

[image: quiero mostrar solo el nombre en un tipo text el problema que solo e podido en un tipo select]

esta es mi consulta

```
 $motivo_llegada = \DB::table('llegadas_tardias_empleado')
            ->join('motivo_llegadas_tardias', 'motivo_llegadas_tardias.id', '=', 'llegadas_tardias_empleado.motivo_llegada')
            ->select('motivo_llegadas_tardias.nombre', 'motivo_llegadas_tardias.id')->where('llegadas_tardias_empleado.id', '=', $id)->pluck('nombre');

        $llegadas_tardias_empledo = llegadas_tardias_empleado::findOrFail($id);


        $pdf = PDF::loadView('llegadas_tardias_pdf', [

            'llegadas_tardias_empledo' =>$llegadas_tardias_empledo,
             'motivo_llegada' =>$motivo_llegada
        ]);

         return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');

    }
```

aqui esta mi formulario donde los muestro

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('identidad', 'Motivo llegada:', ['class' => 'col-lg-3 control-label']) !!}
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input class="form-control typeahead" type="text" readonly value="{{$motivo_llegada['nombre']}}"/>
    </div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Hora_llegada</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input class="form-control typeahead" type="text" readonly value="{{$llegadas_tardias_empledo->hora_llegada}}"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no se entiende muy bien lo que quieres hacer

Comment: es que el dato que me trae me lo trae en tipo arreglo el problema es ala hora de mostrarlo yo quiero que me muestre solo el nombre normal asi como en el segundo input pero me lo esta mostrando como que esta en un arreglo y creo que el problema lo tengo en la consulta

Comment: Entiendo, y si tratas de acceder a la posición 5 que muestra el objeto?

Comment: como podria hacerlo

Comment: lo intente de esta forma readonly value="{{$motivo_llegada['nombre']}} pero me tira como que el nombre esta indefinido

Comment: No me queda claro el código `html` por que la imagen muestra **motivo de llegada** y el código no muestra esa parte

Comment: ahorita lo corregi para que tengas una mejor idea

Comment: corregi el controlador y el html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no me equivoco, el fallo esta aquí:

```
$motivo_llegada = \DB::table('llegadas_tardias_empleado')
            ->join('motivo_llegadas_tardias', 'motivo_llegadas_tardias.id', '=', 'llegadas_tardias_empleado.motivo_llegada')
            ->select('motivo_llegadas_tardias.nombre', 'motivo_llegadas_tardias.id')->where('llegadas_tardias_empleado.id', '=', $id)->pluck('nombre')->all();
```

Ahora tendras un array con todos los motivos que correspondan, añadiendo el metodo `all()`.

Asi que el input ha de ser asi:

```
<input class="form-control typeahead" type="text" readonly value="{{$motivo_llegada[0]}}"/>
```

Si solo te interesa el primer valor, sustituye el `all()` por `first()`, asi no tendras que especificar indice en el input

Comment: muchas gracias ese era el problema que tenia